# Django: 'bool' object is not subscriptable when trying to get value from queryset

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to get a value from a queryset, but i keep getting this error that says `'bool' object is not subscriptable`.

I have a queryset that looks like this `tax_rate_fee = TaxRate.objects.filter(country=cartorder.country).exists()` and i am checking to see if a specific country exists in the Queryset, then i want to grab a value from the queryset and perform some operation.

This is my code

```
tax_rate_fee = TaxRate.objects.filter(country=cartorder.country).exists()
if tax_rate_fee:
    cartorderitem.vat = 5 * tax_rate_fee['rate']
```

this is the tax rate fee model

```
class TaxRate(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rate = models.IntegerField(default=5, help_text="Numbers added here are in percentage (5 = 5%)")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: .exists() callend on queryset is returning boolean value, so tax_rate_fee is boolean